# Array.forEach Callback at the end

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, es6-promise

I'm using `Array.forEach` function of javascript to get a different message for each element of a list. So I'm using `forEach` function and I'm looking for a `way` to execute my `callback` function `cb(result)` when the foreach as finished to both execute `.forEach` and `msgAfterTimeout`. I read that there was something called `promises` but I don't really get how I can use them here.

```
function msgAfterTimeout (who, timeout, onDone) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        onDone(" Hello " + who + "!");
    }, timeout);
}
var test="";
var list = [{name:"foo",surname:"bar"},{name:"Jean",surname:"dupond"}];

function dispName(cb)
{
    list.forEach(function(item, index)
    {
        msgAfterTimeout(item.name, 200, function (msg) 
        {
            test=msg+"\n";

        });
        cb(result);

    });

}

dispName(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: what is result supposed to contain? It is undefined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your example with Promises:

```js
var list = [{name: "foo", surname: "bar"}, {name: "Jean", surname: "dupond"}];


function msgAfterTimeout(who, timeout) {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(
            () => resolve(" Hello " + who + "!"),
            timeout)
    );
}


Promise.all(
    list.map(item => msgAfterTimeout(item.name, 200))
).then(
    result => console.log(result.join('\n'))
);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

```
function msgAfterTimeout (who, timeout, onDone) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        onDone(" Hello " + who + "!");
    }, timeout);
}

var test= "";
var list = [{name:"foo",surname:"bar"},{name:"Jean",surname:"dupond"}];

function newFunc(list, i, endCb) {
     var name = list[i].name;
     msgAfterTimeout(name, 200, function(msg) {
          var test = msg + "\n";
          console.log(test);
          if(i+1 == list.length) {
              endCb();
          }
          else {
             newFunc(list, i+1, endCb);
          }
     });
}

function dispName(cb)
{
      newFunc(list, 0 , cb);    
}

dispName(function(){
    console.log("Done with all!");
});
```

This outputs:

> Hello foo!
>   Hello Jean!
>   Done with all!

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` processes things in *series*, so for the sake of this answer, let's assume that's a requirement. `Promise.all` as demonstrated by @georg will process the items in *parallel* – it's a good answer but it won't help you if a series is what you actually need.

The Array.prototype methods `reduce`, `map`, and `forEach` are synchronous, but you could easily make an asynchronous variants. You're using `forEach` here but you're actually performing a `reduce` by hand. So we'll start by implementing an asynchronous `reducek` and then go from there

Don't worry too much about understanding `reducek` itself. All you need to know is the primary difference between `reducek` and `reduce` is that the reducing function receives an extra callback argument that is called when each item is done, and `reducek` has its own callback for when the entire input list is done.

```js
function reducek (f, acc, [x, ...xs], k) {
  if (x === undefined)
    return k (acc)
  else
    return f (acc, x, y => reducek (f, y, xs, k))
}

function msgAfterTimeout (who, timeout, onDone) {
  return setTimeout(onDone, timeout, "Hello " + who + "!")
}

function messageReducer (acc, item, done) {
  return msgAfterTimeout(item.name, 200, function (text) {
    return done([...acc, text])
  })
}

function displayName (list, done) {
  // use our async reduce here
  return reducek (messageReducer, [], list, done)
}

var list = [{name:"foo",surname:"bar"},{name:"Jean",surname:"dupond"}]

displayName (list, function (texts) {
  console.log("Done!", texts.join(' '))
})

// Done! Hello foo! Hello Jean!
```

**Important things to notice ...**

1. No longer performing reduce by hand – instead of using a `test` variable initialized with state of `''` (empty string), `reducek` accepts the initial value as an argument.
2. Here we're using an initial state of of `[]` (empty array) to store each of the texts. When we're done, we join the texts together using `texts.join(' ')`.

---

**Not Another Ceremony ...**

All of that is a lot of ceremony and continuations are not necessarily the best for asynchronous flow control. In fact, Promises were brought to JavaScript because a better tool was needed.

```
// instead of returning a timeout, return a Promise
function msgAfterTimeout (who, timeout) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout, "Hello " + who + "!")
  })
}

// new async/await syntax - work with Promises in a most elegant fashion
// no more callback parameter; async implicitly returns a Promise
async function displayName (list) {
  let texts = []
  for (let item of list)
    texts.push(await msgAfterTimeout(item.name, 200))
  return texts
}

var list = [{name:"foo",surname:"bar"},{name:"Jean",surname:"dupond"}]

// instead of a callback, chain a .then on the returned Promise
displayName(list).then(texts => console.log("Done!", texts.join(' ')))

// Done! Hello foo! Hello Jean!
```

Note: If you need to support older browsers, `async`/`await` needs to be transpiled using something like Babel.